# Storing processes in a list or array or dictionary using execlp

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

How does one keep track of multiple execlp processes in an array, dictionary, list? I want to store the index, pid and command line with the process.

Comment: Same way you keep track of anything else in an array, dictionary, list?

Comment: I was wondering which one is more efficient @immibis

Comment: Do you have an implementation of a dictionary in C? If not, it'll take time and effort to create one — it probably isn't efficient use of your time.  Do you know how to program lists in C?  If not, you'll need to learn how to do so, but that's probably a good exercise anyway.  Do you know how to use arrays of structures?  If so, that's the easiest way.  Do you know how many entries you might need to handle?  If the number is not too big, maybe you can use a fixed size array.  If the number is big, you probably need to use dynamic array allocation — which is also an important technique to know.

Comment: I would consider `execlp()` as expensive function. Comparing this to searching an ID (probably something like an `int`) in an array, the latter is cheap even if done trivially by comparing entries one by one consecutively - nothing to worry about. You even didn't describe what you want to do with the _array, dictionary_ of process IDs. Just storing them, a list or array (as recommended by Jonathan) should be fully sufficient - not worth the effort to even think about something like a _dictionary_.